# Extracting sentences which contains the french word "mais" return sentences which do not contains it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Good morning,

I am trying to extract sentences which contains the word "mais" from a file , the problem I am encountering is that , the sentences which are extracted do not contain at all  "mais" but sometimes "jamais". Do you know why ? I put a small example to illustrate my question ?

Find below  :  the script I wrote used spacy for the tokenisation of sentences  so I just illustrated a small portion. These lines follow the line which read the file and put it a list. then i loop inside the list to find the elt which contains "mais".

```
    sentences_list_num = ['je ne suis pas mauvais mais lourd','je ne suis pas gentil', 'ce n\'est pas 
    plus laid', 'ce ne sera jamais bordelique']

    # Importing sentences which contains "mais"  ; result  :7477 sentences
    #word = 'mais'
    for sent in sentences_list_num:
      if 'mais' in sent:
        sentences_with_word_mais.append(sent)
      else :
        sentences_no_mais.append(sent)

    print(sentences_with_word_mais)
```

Printing return 2 sentences wheras it is just one sentence :

```
['je ne suis pas mauvais mais lourd', 'ce ne sera jamais bordelique'] # Jamais is not mais ???
```

Since I have a huge file I did not notice the error from the start but when I try to insert another code line I found this error.

I used also the "for" but It is still giving me the same error.

Comment: You should use a regular expression to find only the whole word.

Comment: Actually, `mais` is inside there - in `jamais` :) If you want to extract the word, as a word, `mais` and not as part of another word, you need to use something more "clever" (such as, chekcing the word with spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String matching does not account for word boundaries. So, according to Python, 'mais' is in 'mais' and 'jamais'. You'll need to somehow specify that 'mais' needs to be its own word. You could use a regular expression:

```
for sent in sentences_list_num:
  if len(re.findall(r'\Wmais\W', sent)) > 0:
    sentences_with_word_mais.append(sent)
  else:
    sentences_no_mais.append(sent)
```

If you're already using spacy to tokenize, you could also just iterate over the tokens in each sentence and look for 'mais'.

Comment: Hello, I have another question in the case I have a list of terms for exemple ['trop manger', 'pas trop bon'] , how can I loop inside the list with regular expression and then serach in my list of sentences if the words are  present. I used for loop, but it extracts me sentences which have "manger " whereas I want only "trop manger" in the sentences. the solution you offer is good but how can I transpose it with a list of word.